# Limitar el recorrido de un api con react js

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, map

Hola estoy consumiendo un api, este me devuelve 100 registros y solo quiero printear 6.

agradezco si me pueden dar una guia para resolver esto

hay algunos apis que ya tienen desarrollados algunos queries para esto pero en este caso es algo que debo consumirlo desde JS

Gracias de antemano

Saludos

```
class EpisodesCardsGrid extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            episodes: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://breakingbadapi.com/api/episodes')
            .then(resp =>{
                this.setState({
                    episodes: resp.data
                })
            })
    }
    render(){
        const { episodes } = this.state;
        return(
            <>
            {
                episodes.map(
                    u => (
                        <EpisodesCard
                            key     = {u.id}
                            title   = {u.title}
                        />
                    ))
            }
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default EpisodesCardsGrid
```

Answer (score 2):

Podemos cortar el resultado de `resp.data`, esto limitara la renderizacion de los datos.

Para esto ocuparemos el metodo `slice()`, puedes encontrar mas informacion [en esta documentcion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
axios.get('https://breakingbadapi.com/api/episodes')
.then(resp =>{
  const limit = 6;

    this.setState({
        // el cero representa desde donde quieres cortar el array.
        // y la constante limit (int) sera el maximo dato a cortar
        episodes: resp.data.slice(0, limit)
    })
})
```

Comment: Amigo Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Me sirvió de mucho

Comment: @EnriqueJoseEstradaNuñez puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta